# Powershell script ignoring $userInput variable

Tags: powershell, syntax, comparison-operators

```
function processSearch {
Get-Process -Name "$processSearch*"
}

function processKill {
Stop-Process -Name "$processSearch*"
}

$processSearch = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the full or partial name of the process: "

processSearch

 if ((Get-Process -Name "$processSearch*") -eq $null) {
    Write-Output "ERROR: NO PROCESS FOUND."
    [Threading.Thread]::Sleep(3000) 
 }

if ((Get-Process -Name "$processSearch*") -ne $null) {
    $userInput= Read-Host -Prompt "Kill process?"
} 
     
if ($userInput -eq "y" -or "Y") {
    processKill
}
elseif ($userInput -eq "n" -or "N") {
    Write-Output "Process not killed."   
}
else {
    Write-Output "ERROR: UNHANDLED INPUT."
}
```

When my script gets to `$userInput= Read-Host -Prompt "Kill process?"`, and I enter any text, the script will terminate the selected process.

I'm new to scripting, so please let me know where my logic is flawed, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is because when you're checking the `$userInput` variable you've forgotten to declare what variable to check against in your `-or` part of the clause.

This code:

```
if ($userInput -eq "y" -or "Y") {
    processKill
}
elseif ($userInput -eq "n" -or "N") {
    Write-Output "Process not killed."   
}
else {
    Write-Output "ERROR: UNHANDLED INPUT."
}
```

should become:

```
if ($userInput -eq "y" -or $userInput -eq "Y") {
    processKill
}
elseif ($userInput -eq "n" -or $userInput -eq "N") {
    Write-Output "Process not killed."   
}
else {
    Write-Output "ERROR: UNHANDLED INPUT."
}
```

You could also make the if statements a little less verbose by using the case-sensitive [-cin operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-in-and--notin) as this will check if the value is in an array of given values as below:

```
if ($userInput -cin "y", "Y") {
    processKill
}
elseif ($userInput -cin "n", "N") {
    Write-Output "Process not killed."   
}
else {
    Write-Output "ERROR: UNHANDLED INPUT."
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  Just a note, `-eq` is case-insensitive so the `-or` part isn't even necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

[NiMux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72673011/45375) makes good points, but it's worth taking a step back:

- **PowerShell's [operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators) are case-*insensitive* by default**:

  - `'y' -eq 'Y'` is `$true`.
- To perform **case-*sensitive*** operations, ***prefix the operator name with `c`***; e.g. `-ceq`:

  - `'Y' -ceq 'Y'` is `$true`, but `'y' -ceq 'Y'` is `$false`.

Therefore:

- `$userInput -eq 'y'` and `$userInput -eq 'n'` are sufficient in your case.
- In case you truly have *multiple* values to test against, use the [`-in`operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin); e.g.:

  - `$userInput -in 'y', 'n', 'c'`

---

As for **what you tried**:

Due to PowerShell's [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence),

```
$userInput -eq "y" -or "Y"
```

is evaluated as:

```
($userInput -eq "y") -or ("Y")
```

That is, the RHS operand of the `-or` operation is string `"Y"` *alone*, and evaluating a *non-empty string* in PowerShell in a Boolean context always yields `$true` (irrespective of what the string contains).

In effect, your attempt was therefore equivalent to the following, which is *always `$true`*:

```
($userInput -eq "y") -or $true
```

The immediate (but suboptimal) fix to your attempt would have been what's shown in NiMux's answer: use of two separate `-eq` operations (`$userInput -eq 'y' -or $userInput -eq 'Y'`).